# Crash on iOS with Picker

Tags: codenameone

I have a problem with my application on iOS only (iPad 9.7" 11.3.1) when I launch a new Form with a Picker in it (created with GUI Builder). Thanks to a Mac I was able to see some logs :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com_codename1_impl_ios_IOSImplementation.instanceofObjArray:7464
    at com_codename1_io_Util.instanceofObjArray:470
    at com_codename1_ui_spinner_Picker.setType:781
    at fr_aaa_bbb_Saisie.initGuiBuilderComponents:462
    at fr_aaa_bbb_Saisie._INIT__:71
    at fr_aaa_bbb_Saisie._INIT__:67
    at fr_aaa_bbb_Photo.onContinueActionEvent:419
    ...
```

Code at line 462 : `gui_Picker.setType(4);`

Can't see why the is a NullPointerException at this moment because `gui_Picker` is used at the line just before `.setType()`.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, this is a bug in picker fixed [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/e0202064d37bf74b9b11fae464ce27265eb58c18). It will be available in the next Friday update.

As a workaround until then you can use `setStrings()` before (or even instead of) invoking `setType()`.